# How to delete file with no permissions?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1, permissions, windows-explorer

On my HD I have `H:\found.006\dir0000.chk\$Txf`. I cannot delete this folder as I don't have appropriate permissions. If I try to change the permissions I get "You do not have permission to view or edit this object's permission settings."

I really don't care about the folder I just want it to be deleted. I have tried using the command line and safe mode but nothing changes.

This isn't a duplicate. Unlocker doesn't work and neither does `takeown /f`

Comment: Have you tried to take ownership of the file in question?

Comment: Try to run command line below as administrator and take own of this folder. 
   "takeown /f file_name"  and  
"icacls file_name /grant username_or_usergroup:F /q"

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this, but you can boot from an external USB drive with Linux. This does not care about file permissions as the operating system with the files in question has not been loaded. If you do this, make sure you mount the Windows drive to a mount point; usually /mnt is the best point to do this. You can do so with the following command, where X is the number of your Windows partition:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdaX /mnt
```

From there, cd into the mount point and you will have your Windows drive mounted. Then proceed to cd where you want to delete and use this command to delete:

```
rm -rf <location of whatever you want to delete>
```

Keep in mind that you can delete whole directory trees: just specify the folder